# Event on a File Dialog c#

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I'm working in C# VS 2012. I want to be able to have an event for a FileDialog that once the user chooses a file some code is run. So it would be something like once the filedialog is closed the code will run. If anyone can lend any help that would be great.

Comment: Check the FIleDialog `File_Ok` Event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, by default, showing the dialog is modal, i.e., your thread is effectively halted until the dialog is closed.  So, just `Show()` it and any code after that call will be run after the window closes.  You can get the chosen file(s) via the `FileName` property (or `FileNames` property if `MultiSelect` is set to `true`).

Comment: Wow that was easy... thank you

Comment: +1, but technically, the thread isn't really halted... it's just running the message pump of the modal window ;)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Yeah, that's true.

Answer (score 2):

This is for WinForms:

```
  using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog()) {
     if (DialogResult.OK == dialog.ShowDialog()) {
        // work with dialog.FileName
     }
  }
```

Comment: You may want to show how to set the this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok; for the closing form when the form is closed.

Comment: It's also good practice to wrap this in a `using` block.

Comment: @N4TKD In my experience, this is handled internally by OpenFileDialog.

Comment: You are right of course, I was thinking it was a user form.

Answer (score 1):

The FileDialog's ShowDialog method is blocking. This means that the thread it's executed and shown on will stop executing until the file has been returned. You can use the result to check if a file was selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is the WPF way:

```
// Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialog box.
bool? userClickedOK = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

// Process input if the user clicked OK.
if (userClickedOK == true)
{
    ... your code here
}
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: This answer doesn't deserve a downvote; it could be correct, assuming the OP is using WPF (which he didn't say)

Comment: Thanks. Added a comment saying it's WPF specific.